# Deserialization into an array of size 0

Tags: java, serialization

Inside the `load()` method of the Treets class I am declaring an array of Treet objects with size 0. However, when deserializing, I'm saving the results of the `readObject()` method into that very same array. Happens that I was first serializing 2 objects so I'm getting 2 objects when deserializing as well. Why am I not getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception as I'm pushing 2 objects into a previously initialized array of size 0?

**Treet.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Treet implements Comparable<Treet>, Serializable {
    private String mAuthor;
    private String mDescription;
    private Date mCreationDate;
    Treet(String author, String description, Date creationDate) {
        mAuthor = author;
        mDescription = description;
        mCreationDate = creationDate;
    }
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return mCreationDate;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Treet by %s: \"%s\" on %s", mAuthor, mDescription, mCreationDate);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Treet anotherTreet) {
        if(equals(anotherTreet)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return mCreationDate.compareTo(anotherTreet.getCreationDate());
    }
}
```

**Treets.java**

```
import java.io.*;
public class Treets {
    public static void save(Treet[] treets) {
        try(
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("treets.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        )
        {
            oos.writeObject(treets);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static Treet[] load() {
        Treet[] treets = new Treet[0];
        try(
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("treets.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        )
        {           
            treets = (Treet[])ois.readObject();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
        }
        return treets;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Treet treetOne = new Treet("John", "This is treet one", new Date());
        Treet treetTwo = new Treet("Jane", "This is treet two", new Date(1526074720000L));
        Treet[] treets = {treetOne, treetTwo};
        Arrays.sort(treets);
        Treets.save(treets);
        Treet[] loadedTreets = Treets.load();
        for(Treet treet : loadedTreets) {
            System.out.println(treet.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the concept of ObjectInputStream.read.

It doens't fill your declared array, it returns you a new one with the content of the file

```
//A
Treet[] treets = new Treet[0]; //at this moment you are declaring the variable and initializing it with an array of 0 spaces
    try(
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("treets.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    )
    {   //B        
        treets = (Treet[])ois.readObject(); //at this moment you are replacing the pointer of the previous 0 length array to a new one read from the file

    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
    }
    return treets;
}
```

In other words:
On "A", the variable treets is pointing to an address in memory X...
On "B", the variable is changed to point to a new address in memory Y

After the end of the program the content of X is still an array of zero length but you have no variables pointing to it.

if you want to test you can do:

```
Treet[] treets = new Treet[0]; 
Treet[] treetsOld = treets;
    try(
System.out.println(treetsOld == treets);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("treets.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    )
    {          
        treets = (Treet[])ois.readObject(); 
System.out.println(treetsOld == treets);
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
    }
    return treets;
}
```